# Add entries to head of Map using immutablejs

Tags: javascript, dictionary, concatenation, immutable.js

I am working on react . using immutableJs for handling the states.

Suppose if i have Map type data. I want add the data to head.

If i use Map.set(key,value) it adds the value at tail. 
For ex -

```
Immutable.Map({'testKey','testValue'}).set(message_id, anotherMap)  // It adds the value at tail of the map.
```

I tried using `concat` https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/OrderedMap/concat like this -

```
MapIWantToAddAtHead.concat(olderMap)
```

but it doesn't seems to working. 
I havent tried merge yet . 
Is there any other way which i am missing to add entries at head.

Answer (score 0):

Given you are using a Map, I take it that your use case involves keys and values. But for some reason not mentioned in your question above, you also want the new entries to come in the front. I am assuming you are doing this to be able to operate with them in LIFO fashion. And although mentioned fleetingly, you seem to be using OrderedMap which guarantees iteration order of FIFO.
If my assumptions are correct, you can simply invoke the [`reverse`](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Map/reverse) method on your OrderedMap to turn it into LIFO. This way you won't need to fiddle around with the insertion logic, and at the same time you will traverse the Map in the desired order.